# Drawing on Canvas with finger. Tizen native app

Tags: c++, canvas, draw, tizen, tizen-native-app

I just started my adventure with Tizen.

I would like to draw on canvas with my finger, but I can't find an example on how to do this in internet (personally I hate c++). Do you know any good tutorial on how to do this in native application? I managed to do that using javascript (web app) but I would like to know how to do this using c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a sample application called MutipointTouch included with the SDK (in `platforms\tizen2.1\samples\native\cpp\Sample\Tizen Native\MultipointTouch`) which does what you're asking for. There's also [a brief tutorial](https://developer.tizen.org/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.tizen.native.appprogramming%2Fhtml%2Ftutorials%2Fui_tutorial%2Ftask_multipointtouch.htm) at the Tizen website which explains parts of the MultipointTouch application.

In essence, your `Form` will need to inherit from `Tizen::Ui::ITouchEventListener` and implement the touch event methods, like `OnTouchPressed` and `OnTouchMoved`. In those methods you could, for example, perform draw commands on a `Tizen::Graphics::Canvas` (which they show how to do in the MultipointTouch app).